# File supported by BigchainDB

Tags: javascript, blockchain, bigchaindb

BigchainDB support **.json file** format. Is there any possible way to store digital asset like **images**, **documents**?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert any file (seen as a sequence of bits) into JSON, for example, by converting it to base64, which can then be included as the value in a JSON document.

While that *is* possible, it's not a good idea. BigchainDB is more for storing metadata (which you might want to search or query), not for storing big files.

Answer (score 0):

BigchainDB allows interoperability with IPFS. Use the unique hash returned by the IPFS, as when files are added to it, to store as an asset information or as a metadata of the asset in BigchainDB which then can be queried to view the file from IPFS.